# Запись данных из колонки SQL в целочисленный массив

Tags: android, массивы, sqlite, строки

Привет всем.
Подскажите, как переписать колонку из базы данных в целочисленный массив.
Вот колонка, как она объявляется в базе:

```
+ chisla + " integer);";
```

Колонка у меня строковая, хоть я и указываю integer.
А вот так я пытался это сделать

```
int chisl[] = (int)DTB.chisla;
```

Но не получается.
Думаю, может надо сначала записать всю колонку в переменную или можно как-то сразу записать все строки колонки раскидать по элементам массива?

Спасибо за помощь. Все работало по совету shurick31, но у меня одна из колонок возвращала  нуль и из за этого не работала БД.

Comment: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/74-urok-34-hranenie-dannyh-sqlite

Comment: Можно поподробнее?

Comment: Сделайте урок по ссылке полностью сами. И посмотрите что такое SQL и запросы.

Comment: Я уже выполнял урок.
Я пытаюсь извлечь данные вот так 

   int nameColIndex = c.getInt("chisl");

И со строкой, и с целочисленным типом, но в любом случае появляется ошибка о том, что ни String, ни Int не применяется для аргумента String.

Comment: Я в БД совсем не разбираюсь, но попробуйте вот так: берём числа из массива, записываем их в строку. После каждого числа ставим разделитель (какой-нибудь знак типа ♦ или •). Должна получиться строка вроде `1♦2♦3♦4♦5`. Записываем её в базу как строковой ресурс. Для получения числового массива получаем строку из БД, потом вызываем `строка.split("♦");`, получаем на выходе String[]. Ну, а как его переделать в int[], я думаю, объяснять не стоит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

в классе DB нужно определить метод:

```
  public Cursor getTable(tbl_name) {
        String sqlQuery = "select * from " + tbl_name + ";";
        return mDB.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
      }
```

Далее, интересующий нас метод:

```
    DbAdapter db = new DbAdapter(mContext);
    int columnIndex = 3; // Интересующая нас колонка, содержащая числа
    db.open();
    Cursor cursor = db.getTable("TableChisla"); // в классе DB должен быть метод 
    int[] myInts = new int[cursor.getCount()]; // объявляем массив

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) // если курсор не пустой
    {                       
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
        {
            myInts[i] = cursor.getInt(columnIndex); // заполняем
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }           
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
```

Все.

Comment: tbl_name - строка, имя таблицы. В приведенном коде переменной или параметра Table_name нет, есть tbl_name, поэтому и возникает синтаксическая ошибка.
в вызове db.getTable("TableChisla") в кавычках указывается реальное имя таблицы в БД.

Comment: сорри,
public Cursor getTable(tbl_name) поменять на 
public Cursor getTable(String tbl_name)

Comment: Активити - это то что отображается на экране. А для работы с базой методы обычно выносят в отдельный класс - DB.java

package ваш_пакет-(имя пакета такое-же как в main activity)

// import decalarations
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
....
....

public class DB { // собственно объявление класса


....
 public Cursor getTable(String Graph_Table) {
    String sqlQuery = "select * from " + Graph_Table + ";";
    return sdb.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
  }
..
}

как-то так.
Действительно, пройдите урок, ссылка на который дана выше - многое прояснится.

Comment: Я разобрался с бд, подстроил ее под курсор, но не могли бы вы подробнее пояснить про DbAdapter db = new DbAdapter(mContext);
Я смотрел урок, который вы скинули, но не могу разобраться.
И mContext - это не mCtx из класса БД разве?

Comment: Я так и сделал, но
Multiple markers at this line
 - mCtx cannot be resolved to a 
  variable



И подскажите, пожалуйста, как объявить адаптер. Я пытаюсь разобраться, но не получается.